# How to do clean up in generic for iterator function when breaking out of it

Tags: c, lua

I'm implementing a generic for iterator function in C. The function that returns the iterator function for the generic for loop first allocates state information for the iterator function using `lua_newuserdata()`, like this:

```
struct mystate *s = (struct mystate *) lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(struct mystate));
s->firstcall = 1;
```

Then I push the pointer as an upvalue to my C closure, like this:

```
lua_pushvalue(L, lua_gettop(L));
lua_pushcclosure(L, iteratorfunction, 1);
```

My iterator function then retrieves the pointer from the first upvalue and does some allocations on it, like this:

```
static int iteratorfunction(lua_State *L)
{
    struct mystate *s = (struct mystate *) lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));

    if(s->firstcall) {
       s->file = fopen(...);
       s->data = malloc(...);
       ...
       s->firstcall = 0;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now my question is this: How should I make sure that `s->file` and `s->data` are freed correctly in case the script uses `break` to exit the generic for loop before it has finished? In that case, my `iteratorfunction` can't do the clean up because it isn't called all the way through. Instead, the generic for loop exits before my iterator function has finished.

Precisely, how can I make sure that `fclose()` is called on `s->file` and `free()` is called on `s->data` in case the script uses `break` to exit my generic for loop before it has finished?

I've had a look at the Lua source and `io.lines` seems to use metatables and the garbage collector to ensure the file handle is closed but I don't really understand how this works. It looks quite complicated and I'm not sure if I should be doing this in a similar way or whether there is an easier solution for my case.

Note that I'm still on Lua 5.0 so any suggestions for solutions should keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid there is no another solution except using finalizers (`__gc` metamethod)

Comment: Thanks, I've just posted a complete answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: In Lua, you can use function-style loops. See my answer below. These are even approved constructs, as that is what `string.gmatch()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I'm now using finalizers (the `__gc` metamethod) as suggested by Egor. In code this looks like this:

First we need to create a metatable whose `__gc` we can use to do the cleaning up:

```
#define PRIVATEHANDLE "PRIVATE*"

luaL_newmetatable(L, PRIVATEHANDLE);
lua_pushliteral(L, "__index");
lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
lua_rawset(L, -3);  

lua_pushstring(L, "__gc");
lua_pushcclosure(L, iteratorfunction_gc, 0);
lua_settable(L, -3);

lua_pop(h, 1);
```

We then need to associate the user data with the metatable so that our `__gc` method is called once Lua decides to delete our user data, hence we do:

```
struct mystate *s = (struct mystate *) lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(struct mystate));
memset(s, 0, sizeof(struct mystate));

luaL_getmetatable(L, PRIVATEHANDLE);
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

Finally, we need to implement `iteratorfunction_gc` to do the actual clean up. This can look like this:

```
static int iteratorfunction_gc(lua_State *L)
{
    struct mystate *s = (struct mystate *) luaL_checkudata(L, 1, FILEHANDLE);

    if(s->file) fclose(s->file);
    if(s->data) free(s->data);

    ...additional cleanup here...

    return 0;
}
```

Tested it and this does the job really fine. Problem solved. No idea why people were trying to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Lua does not provide a means for cleanup in a custom iterator. However, there is a very simple alternative: Use a function-style loop instead.

For example, rather than this construct:

```
for i, line in mylines() do
    if line == "" then break end
    print(line)
end
```

You could implement it thusly:

```
mylines(function(i, line)
    if line == "" then return true end
    print(line)
end)
```

In this case, `mylines()` can easily detect when the function returns `true`, so as to know when to cancel the loop and perform cleanup.

I actually prefer function-style loops, as they allow returning other values to indicate status inside the loop as well, so there is effectively a means of two-way communication. With a custom iterator, you'd need to resort to something more obtuse, such as passing a state table or calling a finalizer function.

```
for i, line, finish in mylines() do
    if line == "" then
        finish()
        break
    else
        print(line)
    end
end
```

About the only disadvantage of function-style loops is that you cannot return out of the *parent* function from witihin the loop context. But, in my experience that is very rarely needed.

Comment: This is pretty much the go-to solution in older Lua versions if immediate cleanup is desired (and `__gc` thus isn't an option). Note that [5.4 addresses this by adding a fourth close value to generic for loops](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5).

Comment: "About the only disadvantage of function-style loops is that you cannot return out of the parent function from witihin the loop context." - Something similar can be achieved by wrapping the iterator usage in a coroutine and yielding from it.